# Flutter Web: google_sign_in_web: Works on desktop and iOS. Fails on Android Chrome

Tags: firebase, google-signin, google-authentication, flutter-web

Simple auth code that links to firebase. The code works fine on mobile iOS Safari and Desktop browsers. The sign in fails (stalls) on Android Chrome.

Simple code snippet:

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future loginGoogle() async {
    try {
      Print('AAA');
      await googleSignIn.signIn();
      print('BBB');
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  //Listener initialized at creation of this class.
  googleSignInListener() {
    return googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) async {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }, onError: (err) => print('Error signing in: $err'));
  }
```

It appears Flutter stalls when the google sign-in popup tab opens on Android. Once the google tab authenticates and closes automatically, flutter tab is restored but does nothing. On Android Chrome, the console output only shows 'AAA'. If I then try to login again after the first failed attempt, same output, only 'AAA' and no google sign-in popup.

No error is printed to the console either.

This code works fine on Desktop browsers and iOS Safari browser.

Is Android stalling applications in background chrome tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. It turns out there are two locations where you have to inform google about website Uri's where authentication can come from and where successful auths can be redirected to. One location is in the google console and the other is under firebase console authentication.

However, I was not able to get the google_sign_in_web package to work still. I used the firebase_auth package and set the google provider in auth request. This works great. Here is a snippet of the adjusted and working code using firebase_auth

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as FA;
//...

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  final FA.FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FA.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FA.GoogleAuthProvider googleAuthProvider = FA.GoogleAuthProvider();
  StreamSubscription<FA.User> authListener;
  //...

  Auth() {
    authListener = signInListener();
    //...
  }

  Future loginGoogle() async {
    await firebaseAuth.setPersistence(FA.Persistence.LOCAL);
    auth = await firebaseAuth.signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider);
  }

  signInListener() {
    return firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().listen((_user) async {
      //Auth state changed...
    });
  }

  //...
}
```